# Custom Taxonomy Not Working When added to WordPress Search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, pre-get-posts, tax-query

I have created custom taxonomies for a custom post type. I have added drop downs to the search form so I can add the custom taxonomies to the search criteria.

The problem I am having is that when my query includes a particular taxonomies, I get no returns, even though I should. When I check the SQL query, it is inserting 0 = 1 which usually means that it can't find any results for the taxonomy (or there is a problem with the tax_query part of the overall query).

If I simply create a custom query (WP_Query) using the same tax_query parameters, I get results. So I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work in the Search context but does work in a custom query.

Here is the custom taxonomy as I've created it:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => __( 'Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'singular_name'     => __( 'Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Sexes', 'hrd_record' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Sexes', 'hrd_record' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Sex:', 'hrd_record' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Sex', 'hrd_record' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Sex Name', 'hrd_record' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Sexes', 'hrd_record' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'sex' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'sex', '', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'sex', 'hrdrecord' );
```

My search form includes other taxonomies and here is the code I am using which is added to the filter 'pre_get_posts':

```
if ($query->is_search) {

$tax_query = array();
$meta_query = array();


 $query->set('post_type','hrdrecord');

 $region = (isset($_GET['region'])) ? (int)$_GET['region'] : '';
 $country = (isset($_GET['country'])) ? (int)$_GET['country'] : '';
 $state = (isset($_GET['state'])) ? (int)$_GET['state'] : '';

 $sex = (isset($_GET['sex'])) ? (int)$_GET['sex'] : '';
 $sector = (isset($_GET['sector'])) ? $_GET['sector'] : '';
 $sector_detail = (isset($_GET['sector_detail'])) ? $_GET['sector_detail'] : '';

 $nickname = (isset($_GET['nickname'])) ? $_GET['nickname'] : '';

  if (!empty($nickname)) {
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
        'meta_key'     => '_nickname',
        'meta_value'   => $nickname,
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    );
  }


  if (!empty($state)) {
    $location = $state;
  } elseif (!empty($country) && empty($state)) {
    $location = $country;
  } elseif (!empty($region) && empty($country) & empty($state)) {
    $location = $region;   
  }

  $tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND', );

  if (!empty($location)) {  //Location

    array_push($tax_query, array('taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $location,
            'include_children' => false,
            ));

  } 

  if (!empty($sex)) {  //Sex

    array_push($tax_query, array('taxonomy' => 'sex',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $sex,
            ));

  } 

  if (!empty($sector)) { //Sector

    array_push($tax_query, array('taxonomy' => 'sector',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $sector,
            ));

  } 

  if (!empty($sector_detail)) { //Sector Detail

    array_push($tax_query, array('taxonomy' => 'sector-detail',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $sector_detail,
            ));

  } 

if (!empty($tax_query)) {
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}

if (!empty($meta_query)) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}

}

return $query;
```

So if I have values for any of the other taxonomies or a combination of them...I get results but the minute I add a value for the 'sex' taxonomy, there are no results...even though the same query done using WP_Query will return results.

In fact my fix for this is to add this custom theory in my search.php template in the event I have no results (I check if sex was not empty in the query string and then run my custom theory---but I'd rather sort out why it's not picking it up in the first instance)